# Inline comments in LaTeX

Tags: vim, highlighting, comments

Is it possible to make inline comments in LaTeX that do not extend until the end of the line?

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is vim's annoying highlighting of the non-curly end-bracket here:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{
    \arabic{section}.
    \alph{subsection})
}
```

**Update**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: VIM does not highlight `)` in any way for me. Also note that your definition introduces three spaces, which will appear when the command is used. Add `%` at line ends to remove the spaces. Finally, how about trying [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for this task?

Comment: Wouldn't `\renewcommand...{%(` fix your paren problem?

Comment: @Andrey: I added a picture. Thanks for the `%` tip; I didn't think it would work because of the indentation. I'll look inteo `titlesec`.

Comment: @Ulrich: For some reason, it does not. I figured that vim is smart enough to understand that it is commented out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a command, which gobbles its argument, such as in the comment here: [Control command arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/control-command-arguments):

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
```

If you just wish to gobble a character, name it so and use it like

```
\newcommand*{\commentchar}[1]{}
Text \commentchar()
```

which results in *Text )*.

Another way, shown by Joseph on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=8320#p32165) is defining an active character for that, such as in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\|=\active
\def|#1|{}
\begin{document}
Text |ignored|Text
\end{document}
```

You have to take care of the spacing (blanks before and after) and possible side effects. This environment-way is fine, though again vim might unserstand that it's commented out, unlinke the `\commentchar` way.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. What does the asterisk in your `\commentchar` definition do?

Comment: @Tim It defines a macro that is not `\long`, meaning that TeX will fail with an error if the paragraph ends while reading the argument.

Comment: Maybe you'd also want to use `\ignorespaces`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276698/35642

Answer (score 1):

**Stefan already explained well but maybe it can be helpful too. So take a glance.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}

\begin{document}

first sentence.\ignore{second sentence.} third sentence.

\end{document}
```

**Output:** first sentence. third sentence.