# Commenting out a few words within a paragraph?

Tags: comments

Is there anyway by which I can comment out a word within a sentence?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "comment[ing] out a word within a sentence"? Please provide us with an example.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to cite a few papers, but I was't sure if one of them was the correct reference. I wanted to leave a note for myself to check that specific reference later.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into using the [`todo` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/todo). Your goal seems different than the question though...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

I like bacon, sausage,
% pork chops,
and ham.

% Note to self... try pork chops

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 36):

You can do this:

```
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{}
...
\begin{document}

Hello \cmmnt{commented text} bye.

\end{document}
```

A comment suggests eliminating undesired spaces around the comment:

```
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\ignorespaces}
...
```

(This should be part of some "comment" package, if it is not already.)

Comment: You could throw in a \ignorespaces

Comment: Do you mean use `\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\ignorespaces}` to avoid creating spurious spaces in the text (coming from surrounding the command with actual spaces)?

Comment: Ja.  Da.  Oui.  Si.  (Is that 15 letters yet?)

Comment: Perhaps even better than `\ignorespaces` is `\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}`. The `\ignorespaces` approach fails with `Lorem\cmmnt{ipsum} dolor`, while `\@bsphack\@esphack` don't (these two macros are used by the LaTeX kernel for commands which don't produce typeset output, like `\label`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201821/134574).

Comment: `\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\makebox[0cm]{}}` is the best way out for me.

Comment: @RubemPacelli, do you know what would be the difference with using `\ignorespaces`?

Comment: @alfC If you use `\ignorespaces`, in some cases (e.g., when you put it between a `\cite` and a period), you still get a white space.

Answer (score 3):

I like the other solutions, but sometimes I wish that my comments would also appear in the output file. I tend to forget important comments that are buried in my source code.

I include

```latex
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
```

in the preamble and can then add in-line comments with

```latex
\todo{This is a comment that will appear in the margin}
```

The result is beautiful "sticky note" comments which appear in the margins of my pdf. I can them remove them when I'm done with my draft.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178806/212801

[Source](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/619-tip-of-the-week-add-inline-or-margin-comments-to-your-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You can put a phantom in a vbox without any height.

```
\vbox to0pt{\phantom{Some wise words.}}
```

The problem with this is, that the comment gets parsed and typeset and therefor must be valid TeX code.