# Changing href's to footnotes

Tags: macros, footnotes

Here is exactly what I am trying to do. I have a file with many commands of the form `\href{a}{b}` for strings `a` and `b`. I would like to redefine `\href` so that it executes the following: `\footnote{\href{a}{b}}`. Thus want to change the URL's into footnotes to URL's. – Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

This can be done using the standard `\let` technique:

```
\let\oldhref=\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\footnote{\oldhref{#1}{#2}}}
```

Comment: Completing Andrey's answer: `\let\oldhref\href` saves the current meaning of `\href`. You can then use this old version of `\href` in the new definition of `\href`. jrhorn424's solution below would cause an infinite loop as Joseph says below: `\href{a}{b}` would expand to `\footnote{\href{a}{b}}`, and the `\href` in there would expand to `\footnote{\href{a}{b}}`, etc.

Comment: This does not work if the second argument contains active characters. Try `\href{Test}{http://www.test.com/a=3&b=5}`.

Answer (score 6):

This solution also works with URLs that include active characters such as &, % and # (requires `hyperref`):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hreffootnote@[2]{\footnote{\hyper@linkurl{\Hurl{#2}}{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hreffootnote}{\hyper@normalise\hreffootnote@}
\makeatother
```

However, as far as I understand your [blog post](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/tex-is-great-what-is-tex/), you actually want that `\href{a}{b}` behaves like `b\footnote{\url{a}}`. This can be achieved as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myhref@[2]{#2\footnote{\url@{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myhref}{\hyper@normalise\myhref@}
\makeatother
```

Also, see my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote/).

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of `\href` must be handled as verbatim which makes redefinitions tricky. Michael Ummels's answer correctly shows how to use `hyperref`s internal macros for this. However, the recent update of my `newverbs` package provides a way to collect an argument verbatim easily:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/24]

\let\orighref\href
\renewcommand{\href}{\Collectverb{\hrefii}}
\newcommand\hrefii[2]{\footnote{\orighref{#1}{#2}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\href{http://test.com/%$^£$%^_@~}{Test URL}

% With other argument separators as { }:
\lipsum*[2]\href|http://test.com/%$^£$}{%^_@~|{Test URL}

% If a real \href is wanted (also used for comparison here)
\lipsum*[3]\orighref{http://test.com/%$^£$%^_@~}{Test URL}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should disclose that you're the author of `newverbs`.

Comment: @lockstep: Done. I'm never sure about it. When I mention it's my package it sounds like advertising and if I don't, it looks like hidden advertising :-)