# Merging bib files from within LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, verbatim

I have two `.bib` files that I want to use in my bibliography. Entries do not overlap. I have found quite a few forum topics on that, but none of them really satisfied me. So my idea is to merge the two to one `.bib` file which I will use in the `.tex`. Most conveniently, this would be done from within LaTeX (so I do not use `bibtool`, or reference software). So, I made a macro to merge two files:

```
\newwrite\bibwrite
\newcommand{\concatbib}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\CatchFileDef{\bibone}{#1}{}} 
    {\let\bibone\empty}
  \IfFileExists{#2}%
    {\CatchFileDef{\bibtwo}{#2}{}}
    {\let\bibtwo\empty}%
  \immediate\openout\bibwrite=MyBib.bib\relax
  \immediate\write\bibwrite{\bibone \bibtwo}%
  \immediate\closeout\bibwrite
  \endgroup
}
```

which is basically taken from another question ([How can I open a file in "append" mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-append-mode)).
Now the problem is that Latex wants to interpret the file contents, and things like `\noexpand`, `\detokenize`did not work as desired. So I have to read it in verbatim, which I tried according to Martin Scharrer's answer here: [Control command arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/control-command-arguments).

```
\def\alltext{
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % define \do to change the category code of its argument to 'other'
  \dospecials % makro that is a string of every special character preceeded with \do -> all catcodes are changed
  \all@text
}
\def\all@text#1{
  \endgroup
  #1
}
```

and I would use this within the other macro. Testing it alone, though, I get the error that Use of `\all` does not match its definition `\alltext`, and I think that I am missing a big point here.

- I think that I put the definition of `\all@text` after `\alltext` so I can close the group, which to my understanding I need to define the region where the catcodes are altered. But I do not see why `\all@text` should be known already in the definition of `\alltext`?
- up to now I understood that `\@...` commands are primitive commands, but I thought it was only a notation. Is there more to it?
- is there a way to make that code work?

Comment: This is easier than `cat`?

Comment: Do you even need to combine the two files? If they're named, say, `biblio1.bib` and `biblio2.bib`, BibTeX and LaTeX can access both files easily via the statement `\bibliography{biblio1,biblio2}`.

Comment: @Mico I guess you should make that the answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Done! :-)

Comment: Why don't you merge them with jabref?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something about your setup, but do you even need to combine the two `.bib` files?  If they're named, say, `biblio1.bib` and `biblio2.bib`, BibTeX and LaTeX can access both files easily via the statement

```
\bibliography{biblio1,biblio2}
```

If you employ the `biblatex` package, I understand that the preferred style is to use a pair of separate `\addbibresource` statements (cf. section 3.6.1 of the package's [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc)):

```
\addbibresource{biblio1.bib}
\addbibresource{biblio2.bib}
```

Observe that it's necessary to provide the filename extension `.bib` when using the `\addbibresource` command, whereas one should not provide this extension when using the `\bibliography` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of that - sometimes life is easier than you'd think :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do it at the TeX level (which is not really required because you can input as many `.bib` file as you want), here's a set of macro doing it. You can give as mandatory argument to `\concatbib` any number of bib file names (without extension), separated by commas.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% The document level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\concatbib}{ O{output} m }
 {
  \heinrich_concatbib:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% Variables and messages
\ior_new:N \l__heinrich_input_stream
\iow_new:N \l__heinrich_output_stream
\msg_new:nnnn { concatbib } { file-exist }
  { File~`#1'~exists.~Not~overwriting.}
  { The~file~`#1'~already~exists.~I'll~ignore~this~command. }

% Internal functions
% First we check that the named output file doesn't exist 
\cs_new_protected:Npn \heinrich_concatbib:nn #1 #2
 {
  \file_if_exist:nTF { #1.bib }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { concatbib } { file-exist } { #1.bib }
   }
   {
    \__heinrich_concatbib_aux:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
% If we're writing, we open an output stream and cycle
% through the second argument, a comma separated list
% of bib file names
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__heinrich_concatbib_aux:nn #1 #2
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \l__heinrich_output_stream { #1.bib }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \__heinrich_read_write:n { ##1 } }
  \iow_close:N \l__heinrich_output_stream
 }
% At each step we read each line of the current .bib file
% and write it to the output stream
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__heinrich_read_write:n #1
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \l__heinrich_input_stream { #1.bib }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l__heinrich_input_stream
   { \iow_now:Nn \l__heinrich_output_stream { ##1 } }
  \ior_close:N \l__heinrich_input_stream
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% This will concatenate in `output.bib'
\concatbib{foo1,foo2}

% This will concatenate in `foo.bib'
\concatbib[foo]{foo1,foo2}
```

Comment: wow - do you have a suggestion for a good introduction to this? (what do the :n s mean; the ##1 is new to me as well)

Comment: @Heinrich Do `texdoc xparse` and `texdoc interface3`

Answer (score 1):

Hm... I am a big friend of use-the-right-tool-for-the-task. So while intellectually enlightening, I would not go to implement this in LaTeX, but just use the basic OS capabilities (no bibtool or other fancy stuff required):

On Linux/UNIX/MacOS, open a bash (or whatever shell or terminal) in the respective directory and enter:

```
cat bibone.bib bibtwo.bib >MyBib.bib
```

On Windows, open a CMD prompt and enter:

```
type bibone.bib bibtwo.bib >MyBib.bib
```

On both systems you can also *append* to an existing MyBib.bib by redirecting the output with `>>` instead of `>`.